# ObservableCollection<> not notifying view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

I've been searching for a while and I just cannot find what I'm doing wrong.

I have a list of names that I show in a View, in my View I created an itemsControl, the ItemsSource is set to the observableCollection in the ViewModel. The goal is to give a overview of available names in an nxn table. The user should be able to filter the results with the searchbox on top.

First I tried this using a List of Lists which did not work as the view was not being updated according to the string in the searchbox. I found that I should actually use a ObservableCollection because it implements INotifyCollectionChanged. Below I try to implement an ObservableCollection but I fail to update the view when this collection changes.

View (see ItemsControl in the Xaml section):

#### Xaml Resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Button Content="{Binding}" Height="150" Width="150" Margin="20,20,20,20">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2ED99A"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2EB9D9"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333f4a"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
    
</UserControl.Resources>
```

#### Xaml

```
<Grid Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HcfOverviewModel.NSharedModules, StringFormat=Shared Circuits: {0}}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Margin="30,0,0,30" Text="{Binding HcfOverviewModel.NPrivateModules, StringFormat=Private Circuits: {0}}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="20" Content="See Private Circuits"></Button>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Modules, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

#### ViewModel:

```
class HcfOverviewViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    private HcfOverviewModel _hcfOverviewModel;
    private string _pathToSharedModules;
    //private List<List<string>> _modules;
    private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> _modules;

    public HcfOverviewViewModel()
    {
        _pathToSharedModules = @"C:\Users\scamphyn\source\repos\TSD\TSD\TempTestFolder";
        _hcfOverviewModel = new HcfOverviewModel();
        _hcfOverviewModel.NSharedModules = CheckDirectory.FindModules(_pathToSharedModules).Length;
        _hcfOverviewModel.SharedModuleNames = CleanModuleNames(CheckDirectory.FindModules(_pathToSharedModules));
        //_modules = CreateGridLayout(_hcfOverviewModel.SharedModuleNames);
        _modules = CreateGrid(_hcfOverviewModel.SharedModuleNames);
    }

    public HcfOverviewModel HcfOverviewModel
    {
        get => _hcfOverviewModel;
    }
    
    public void Filter(string searchString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(searchString);
        if (searchString == "")
        {
            //Modules = CreateGridLayout(_hcfOverviewModel.SharedModuleNames);
            Modules = CreateGrid(_hcfOverviewModel.SharedModuleNames);
        }
        else
        {
            Modules.Clear();
            string[] filteredNames = _hcfOverviewModel.SharedModuleNames.Where(n => n.Contains(searchString)).ToArray();
            //Modules = CreateGridLayout(filteredNames);
            Modules = CreateGrid(filteredNames);
        }
    }

    private string[] CleanModuleNames(string[] listToClean)
    {
        List<string> moduleNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (string s in listToClean)
        {
            string[] listPath = s.Split('\\');
            string name = listPath[listPath.Length - 1];
            moduleNames.Add(name);
        }
        return moduleNames.ToArray();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> CreateGrid(string[] moduleNames)
    {
        ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> lsts = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>();
        int circuitsPerRow = 4;
        int _nRows = moduleNames.Length / circuitsPerRow;
        Queue<string> modules = new Queue<string>(moduleNames);
        for(int i = 0; i <= _nRows; i++)
        {
            lsts.Add(new ObservableCollection<string>());
            for (int j = 0; j < circuitsPerRow; j++)
            {
                if (modules.Count != 0)
                {
                    lsts[i].Add(modules.Dequeue());
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return lsts;
    }

    public List<List<string>> CreateGridLayout(string[] moduleNames)
        //To Create the grid in HcfOverview
    {
        List<List<string>> lsts = new List<List<string>>(); // create list of list to store nxn matrix data in.
        int circuitsPerRow = 4;
        //Determine correct size nxn
        int _nRows = moduleNames.Length / circuitsPerRow;
        //Create Queue
        Queue<string> modules = new Queue<string>(moduleNames);
        //Create data for ItemControls
        for (int i = 0; i <= _nRows; i++) // number of rows
        {
            lsts.Add(new List<string>());
            
            for (int j = 0; j < circuitsPerRow; j++) // number of columns
            {
                if (modules.Count != 0)
                {
                    lsts[i].Add(modules.Dequeue());
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return lsts;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> Modules
    {
        get => _modules;
        set {
            _modules = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Modules");
        }
    }

}
```

"_modules" which is my ObservableCollection is populated in the CreateGrid Method.

Here is what it looks like in the window:

[image]

The search box is in the "parent" View/ViewModel when I detect an update there I call the filter method in my ViewModel shown above to update the ObservableCollection.

How can this be resoloved?

## Update:

Because I've been stuck on this issue for week now I decided to create a new "Project" and check if I could get it to work in a simplified project.
In this simplified project I managed to add and remove rows. I used the exact same methods as I was using before. So the binding and updating of my observablecollection is done right. I now wonder if this issue would be in how I load this UserControl. The UserControl displaying this data is loaded through another View. see code below:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding CurrentHcfViewModel}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:HcfOverviewViewModel}">
                <views:UserControlHcfOverview/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>
```

My HcfOverviewViewModel is loaded into a usercontrol that exists in a different view. Could this have influence on the updating of the ObeservableCollection and its View in the HcfOverviewViewModel?

Comment: Give the detail of `DataTemplate_Level1`, please.

Comment: Please describe what exactly the problem is. Does the display in the ItemsControl not reflect the current content of the `Modules` collection?

Comment: Try this: 
ItemsSource="{Binding Modules, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: @GellioGao I updated the View with the complete code so you can have a look at DataTemplate_Level1.

at KlausGütter Yes correct, initially on "first load" its correct but it does not change according to what is typed in the searchbox. In the picture which shows the UI, If I would type "new" in the searchbox, all other boxes should disappear except for the "newTestModule.hcf".

at Frank I updated the ItemsSource binding with "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" but the result is the same.

Comment: I think your problem is that Filter method is not getting called as you think. Please verify if that is the issue.

Comment: @Mat J I checked if the filter was getting called with a Console.WriteLine statement and it does. I think I will have to rewrite a hole bunch of code to get the functionality I want as explained by OmegaMan.

Answer (score 1):

> I found that I should actually use a ObservableCollection because it implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

Due to how you do your update its not working as you believe. When one changes the **reference** from one `ObservableCollection` to another `ObservableCollection`, that does not send a `INotifyCollectionChanged` message. Only add/delete/clear calls generate that message on an **active** referenced collection.

When you reset the reference you are telling the `ItemsControl` to fully clear itself and then show what is being cleared.

You need to not change the initial `Modules` collection after it is created. There are other issues with your logic that cascade from that and unless someone rewrites your custom control/logic, this question cannot be fully answered.

Regardless you need to start with not changing the references and then work on the changing internal collection items in the same pattern to the parent `ObservableCollection`.

---

Note, some controls need a `Null` to  be set when one is setting to a new list. Its unclear if that is also compounding the issue, for you immediately change to the newer reference and the new reference top level does not seem to change the whole `ItemsControl`.

Comment: I will try to rewrite the code to implement this, if I can't get it fixed I will rewrite the whole logic for the table. Will update the question with the results later. Thanks.